# GuestToken config is not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

We have added the GuestToken setting to nginx, but it is not functioning and is returning an unauthorised error. Please advise if the configuration `proxy_set_header X-GuestToken $http_x_guesttoken;` is correct.

We are adding below GuestToken in nginx configuration and it is not working:

```
proxy_set_header X-GuestToken $http_x_guesttoken;
```

I am expecting correct configuration of above header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can add this line to the `nginx` configuration to allow any headers to be passed through, and test it again:

```
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
```

and also verify that the `X-GuestToken` header is being sent from the client. To do this, you can use `cURL` or `Postman` to inspect the headers being sent in the request.